# how to create a dynamic update query with variables?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to create the below dynamic update query with some variables and for some reason, it's not working inside the stored procedure. Can someone suggest to me where I am doing wrong and what's the best practice by avoiding the SQL Injection as well?

```
    DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)
    DECLARE @COLUMN1 NVARCHAR(10)
    DECLARE @COLUMN2 NVARCHAR(10)
    DECLARE @TABLENAME NVARCHAR(10)

    SET @SQL = 'UPDATE TL
                SET '+ @COLUMN1 + '= AB.COLUMN1,'
                    + @COLUMN2 + '= AB.COLUMN2
                FROM' + @TABLENAME + ' TL
                JOIN ABACUS AB
                ON TL.REF = AB.REF
                AND TL.SUBS = AB.SUBS
                WHERE ' + @COLUMN1 + ' IS NULL
                AND ' + @COLUMN2 +' IS NULL';

    SET @COLUMN1 = (SELECT CONCAT('USER_ID', '8'))
    SET @COLUMN2 = (SELECT CONCAT('USER_ID', '6'))
    SET @TABLENAME = 'POLICYREF';
    EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL, @TABLENAME, @COLUMN1, @COLUMN2;

    SET @TABLENAME = 'USERREF';
    EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL, @TABLENAME, @COLUMN1, @COLUMN2;
```

Comment: `CAST(8 AS CHAR(1))` can just be a string `'8'` or even a number `8` if you don't care about the string conversion.

Comment: Thanks @markschultheiss Updated the question with a string.

Comment: Define "not working".  And you're missing a space here `@COLUMN2 +'IS NULL';`

Comment: @DAVIDBROWNE-MICROSOFT Thanks, I have added the space now. It doesn't like if I do `SET @TABLENAME = 'POLICYREF'`. I got a syntax near 'POLICYREF'.

Comment: @jaimedrq Thanks, the other part '8' would change according to the other select statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need dynamic SQL, not parameters.  You can't parameterize column names or table names.  So something like:

```
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @COLUMN1 NVARCHAR(10) = 'USER_ID8'
DECLARE @COLUMN2 NVARCHAR(10) = 'USER_ID6'
DECLARE @TABLENAME NVARCHAR(10) = 'POLICYREF'

SET @SQL = 'UPDATE TL
            SET '+ quotename(@COLUMN1) + '= AB.COLUMN1,'
                 + quotename(@COLUMN2) + '= AB.COLUMN2
            FROM ' + quotename(@TABLENAME) + ' TL
            JOIN ABACUS AB
            ON TL.REF = AB.REF
            AND TL.SUBS = AB.SUBS
            WHERE ' + quotename(@COLUMN1) + ' IS NULL
            AND ' + quotename(@COLUMN2) +' IS NULL';

EXEC (@SQL)

SET @TABLENAME NVARCHAR(10) = 'USERREF'
SET @SQL = 'UPDATE TL
            SET '+ quotename(@COLUMN1) + '= AB.COLUMN1,'
                 + quotename(@COLUMN2) + '= AB.COLUMN2
            FROM ' + quotename(@TABLENAME) + ' TL
            JOIN ABACUS AB
            ON TL.REF = AB.REF
            AND TL.SUBS = AB.SUBS
            WHERE ' + quotename(@COLUMN1) + ' IS NULL
            AND ' + quotename(@COLUMN2) +' IS NULL';


EXEC (@SQL)
```

Comment: I have asked a question to Mark above, can you guide me as well whether it's possible or not please?

Comment: If you are asking if you can reference a temp table in dynamic SQL, the answer is yes.

Comment: `QUOTENAME` is missing in many places, as is a space after `FROM`

Answer (score 1):

Not a huge fan of this but, given that, create a stored procedure OR re-arrange to execute each after updating the `@SQL`, here is the stored procedure example:
Note this is missing production level things like a transaction, `TRY CATCH` etc. and is only for an basic UNTESTED example

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.MyFunQuery
    @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @COLUMN1 NVARCHAR(10),
    @COLUMN2 NVARCHAR(10),
    @TABLENAME NVARCHAR(10)
AS 
BEGIN
   SET @SQL = 'UPDATE TL
   SET '+ @COLUMN1 + '= AB.COLUMN1,'
   + @COLUMN2 + '= AB.COLUMN2
   FROM ' + @TABLENAME + ' AS TL
   JOIN ABACUS AS AB
   ON TL.REF = AB.REF
   AND TL.SUBS = AB.SUBS
   WHERE ' + @COLUMN1 + ' IS NULL
              AND ' + @COLUMN2 + ' IS NULL;';

 EXECUTE ( @SQL );
END
```

--Now to call it:

```
DECLARE @COLUMN1 NVARCHAR(10) = 'USER_ID8',
        @COLUMN2 NVARCHAR(10) = 'USER_ID6';
EXECUTE dbo.MyFunQuery @COLUMN1, @COLUMN2, @TABLENAME='POLICYREF';
EXECUTE dbo.MyFunQuery @COLUMN1, @COLUMN2, @TABLENAME='USERREF';
```

Comment: Thanks Mark. One question, would it be possible to use a temp table instead of a hardcoded table name 'ABACUS'. Basically, this `ABACUS` table is a User defined function which returns a temp table.

Comment: This might help on the UDF https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/86143/44556

Comment: Sorry, it's not quite the same. I have a UDF which returns a table. In my stored procedure, I declared a temp table and insert it to select from the UDF. When I used the temp table name I got an error saying `declare the temp table`

Comment: @Sri That is perhaps a new question "How to insert into a temp table from a UDF" with specific code for that instance example.  Note you might be able to use a CTE but without specific code that is just supposition https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15